# Problem with Prism RegionManager and Unity container

Tags: silverlight-4.0, unity-container, regions, prism-4

I have a main Silverilght project and other modules and I'm using Prism to glue them together along with Unity for Dependency Injection.

I have one of my modules that depends on an `IRegionManager` which, naturally, gets injected to it by Unity.

The issue I'm running to is that, the `Regions` property of the `RegionManager` that I get doesn't contain any regions even though I have declared two of them in my Shell as follows:

```
regions:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"
```

I can't figure out the reason of this behavior. I've tried registering a `RegionManager` as a singleton using

```
Container.RegisterInstance<IRegionManager>(new RegionManager());
```

as well as leaving unity handle this. However, I got the same results :(

what I'm trying to achieve is to inject a view into a particular region and activate it, which can't be done using

```
_regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(MyView));
```

that's why I need to get hold of the "MainRegion" object itself and manipulate it.

I hope somebody has this figured out. I would be very thankful :)

**Edit**:
I should mention that the view discovery works just fine, I can `RegisterViewWithRegion`, but when I check the `Regions` property of the `RegionManager`, I find it empty!

Comment: Does your XAML containing the region define the region's name ?

Comment: yes, of course (see first code snippet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

while thinking about this problem and the context in which it happened, it striked me that, like most bugs in software, the problem wasn't where I was looking!

My setup was as follows: I started out with the Silverlight Business Application project template. this gave me a `MainPage` which I used as my `Shell`, and a couple of views(`Home` and `About`). Now, instead of having the regions sit on my `Shell`, I put them in the `Home` view, keeping the MainPage as kind of a master page.

My take on this is that Prism sets a `RegionManager` for the `Shell`, and passes it around to whoever needs it (using a Dependency Injection Container). This way, when I asked for an `IRegionManager` in my module, I got the one for my `Shell` which doesn't really contain any region (hence the empty `Regions` property).

To **solve** this, all I had to do was put my regions in their rightfull place: **the Shell**, and all is working well (for) now.

**Update**:
Seems like my "take on this" is actually correct :), this is an excerpt from the [Prism Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc707863.aspx): (under **Scoped Regions**)

> Views defining regions with attached properties automatically inherit their parent's RegionManager. Usually, this is the **global RegionManager** that is registered in the *shell* window